# Column Selection - AgGrid Community

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am using `AgGrid` community version with `React`. I am trying to present a checkbox on each column in the header. Which on selection should highlight the cells under that column selected.
Moreover, I need to record the change on the columns selected.

My `columnDefs` are an array of following object built based on data from back-end

```
{headerName: 'Name Of Header', headerCheckboxSelection: true, field: field }
```

**Output**

[image: Checkbox With Each Column Header]

**Problem**

Below is the picture, when I click on **any of the column checkbox** it does two things

1. *Selects other column header checkboxes*
2. *Selects all the rows*

***Whereas* I need to do the following**

1. *Marking only the checkbox that the user checks*
2. *Highlighting only the columns under that column*
3. *Handle the checkbox selection event*

Any pointers?

[image: Selecting any of the checkbox in column headers]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no API for column selection, in the same way as *row selection*, but you are able to use `rangeSelection` method

[here is an interface:](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-range-selection/#api-addcellrange-rangeselection)

```
interface AddCellRangeParams {
    // start row
    rowStartIndex?: number;
    rowStartPinned?: string; // either 'top', 'bottom' or undefined

    // end row
    rowEndIndex?: number;
    rowEndPinned?: string; // either 'top', 'bottom' or undefined

    // columns
    columnStart?: string | Column;
    columnEnd?: string | Column;
    columns?: (string | Column)[];
}
```

a possible scenario based on your task

```
this.gridApi.addCellRange({
  rowStartIndex: 0,
  rowEndIndex: this.rowData.length-1,
  columnStart: "col_3",
  columnEnd: "col_3"
});
```

working <kbd>[**Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/Mp0mhi?p=preview)</kbd>

P.S. Not sure about tracking `headerCheckboxSelection` property event, but seems you have to create own [`headerComponent`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-header-rendering/) and track checkbox event by yourself (and I suppose it's even better to keep everything under your control)